# How do you read data from 3 tables with two 1-to many relationships

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 3 Tables

```
public class Student
{
    public int id;
    public string StudentName
    public int TownId
    public Town Town
}

public class City
{
    public int id;
    public string CityName
    public int CountryId
    public Country Country
    public Icollection<Student>S tudent
}

public class Country
{
    public int id;
    public string CountryName
    public Icollection<City> Cities
}
```

I want to when I click on the details link on a Country inside the county Index page get 2 loops via the controller into the Details page.
The first one will display all the Cities in That country and the second one all the students in that town in the form of a table row.
Something along the lines of

```
| City Name| |Students|<br>
|London    |  |John Doe ,John Doe2|<br>
```

I use the following code to connect the tables inside the Details controller

```
  public IActionResult Details(int? ID) {

            if (ID == null)
                return NotFound();

            var country = DB.Country
                .Where (d => d.Id == ID )
                .Include( d => d.City )
                .ThenInclude( d => d.Student )
                .FirstOrDefault();

            return View( country );    
        }
```

If When I send the model to the csshtml file it loads the Country and City part
It also loads the Student navigator inside City but I cant call up any Student class attributes.

What am I doing wrong? How do I call upon the student attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, the `Student` is a collection and you should iterate it. It would look something like that;

```
var country = DB.Country.Where(d => d.Id == ID).Include(d => d.City)
             .ThenInclude(d=>d.Student).FirstOrDefault();

var students = country.Select(x => x.City.Student);
foreach(var student in students)
{
   //student.StudentName
}
```

Comment: Inside the controller or the View?

Comment: It depends on your requirement. You can iterate it inside a controller or a view.

Comment: if I iterate it inside the controller how am I suppose to send it of the view can only revive one model.

Comment: As I said, I don't know your requirements. I provided an example here to have idea. Put the collection inside your model and iterate it in the view.